# Is there an in person interview for UK general visitor visa applying from US?

Tags: standard-visitor-visas

I am on F-1 student visa in the US and wish to visit UK on my way to India. I have filled out the online application form and collected all required documents which includes document checklist.
I also visited the application center for the biometrics and now I want to mail my package to the visa application center.

Check list mentions that do not sign it until you are at your appointment. I am not sure what appointment is this ? I already went to biometrics appointment and there they never checked for these documents. Also, I am not not sure if there will be an in person interview as nothing about that is mentioned online.

Should I still sign the checklist form and send it to the application center ?

Comment: What checklist are you looking at? IIRC, UK visa forms don't need to be signed in front of a consular officer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes go ahead sign and send. The note that you see is about the biometrics appointment step.  People who deposit their documents on that step have to sign it there.  It has nothing to do with any possible appointment with the Embassy.

To answer your question in the title of this post, Yes such interviews are possible. Generally there are none but they can and do call some candidates for an interview. But as I said the note that you referred to is unrelated to any such interview